# How to create virtual Changeable file?

Tags: delphi

How to create a file which i can Handle all access to this file. my program can send requested data to all program which read from this file and receive all writes to this file.

Comment: "Virtual file" is a file which no real exist on disk or ram. and simulate this by software .

Comment: If it doesn't exist on disk and doesn't exist in RAM, where is it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's virtual - it can be worked with but it is not an object within any filesystem. This is perfectly ok.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp How can you work with something that is not in RAM?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan create it on request, for example. The data can be located elsewhere (across network) and when the request comes for part of this data, the data is streamed and fed to the OS without any buffering. Of course you can treat this as "data in RAM" but technically this is just a temporary storage for a small block of data that lives a short time.

Comment: This is exactly what Virtual Box does and is completely free [link]http://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html

Comment: Does the Delphi IDE use such files? Let me explain: When I create a new project for instance nothing is yet persisted on disk but compilation can be carried out based on code present in RAM held in TStringList objects I presume (My assumption is that the IDE is just a front end to DCC32.exe which is expecting file(s) to process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NTFS Stream:**

NTFS [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404) might be an alternative option.

---

**Quotes from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx):**

> The NTFS file system provides applications the ability to create
>   **alternate data streams of information**. By default, all data is stored
>   in a file's main unnamed data stream, but by using the syntax
>   'file:stream', you are able to **read and write to alternates**...

---

**Other relevant Resources on Stream:**

- [File Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404) (Msdn Page)
- A c++ code sample using Streams is provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537).
- [NTFS Streams](http://www.auditmypc.com/ntfs-streams.asp) (Entry on AuditMyPC.com)
- [NTFS Alternate Streams: What, When, and How To](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml#download)

Comment: That's held on disk and is going to disappear in the next gen Win8 file system.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you need to create a shared memory area using CreateFileMapping / MapViewOfFile - you'll find many examples on the web and in the books.

Comment: For example: http://voiceofgeek.blogspot.com/2009/02/memory-mapped-file-in-delphi.html

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite vague.

If other applications are yours, then you can choose some other interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism rather than use files. Or you can use temporary files (files created with special TEMPORARY attribute).

If other applications are not yours and expect the file to exist on the disk, then you need to either create this file, or create a virtual file system and a disk or a virtual file on existing file system. To create a virtual file system you need a kernel-mode driver (filesystem driver). To create a virtual file on the existing disk you need a kernel-mode filesystem filter driver.

Kernel-mode drivers are tricky and time-consuming to create and require good knowledge of Windows internals. As one of options you can use our Callback File System (CBFS) product, which lets you create a virtual file system in user mode (we provide a driver). But CBFS can be an overkill for your task.

So your better option would be to review your task and requirements and find another way to provide data to other applications.

Comment: for example : i need to create a virtual file which change data for every access of other programs . and not exist this file in ram or disk because for every byte of file access data is changed and this change is by process of my program.

Comment: @MohsenB There's a problem with this approach -- the OS will cache file data once they are read and you won't be able to substitute new data for every read. Also, the data must be the same for all programs (for the same reason - cache). These are limitations / specifics of Windows filesystem architecture, which unlike Unix-like systems treats files as named data, not as some data stream.

Comment: thanks , my end goal is create a virtual file that simulate other file which encrypted and because this encrypted file is very large i want decrept on run time and only block which other program access it .

Comment: @MohsenB Depending on how exactly your file is encrypted and whether you control the way it's encrypted you might be able to live without any virtual files and decrypt the file on the fly. Our CallbackFilter product lets one do exactly this. But in order for the scheme to work your encryption scheme needs to support random access (some encryption modes do).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a named pipe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Here's an example: xxmCGI.exe routes CGI calls from a web-service to a central xxmHost.exe process hosting the named pipe: http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/cgi/xxmCGI.dpr?view=markup http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/cgi/xxmHostRun.pas?view=markup